# Selecting multiple values into single row - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to merge a table with ID and various bit flags like this

```
-----------------
a1 | x |   | x |
-----------------
a1 |   | x |   |
-----------------
a1 |   |   |   |
-----------------
b2 | x |   |   |
-----------------
b2 |   |   |   |
-----------------
c3 | x | x | x |
```

into such form

```
-----------------
a1 | x | x | x |
-----------------
b2 | x |   |   |
-----------------
c3 | x | x | x |
```

The problem is that data are join by kind of option ID each option has an unique ID which is joined with a1, b2. When I try to SELECT it by using DISTINCT I receive results from table number 1. I can make it by subqueries in SELECT but it is really weak solution due to performance reasons.

Do you have any idea how select and combine all these flags into single row?

Comment: Simply GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given result set it is eligible to use  `MIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
tbl.Col
, MIN(tbl.Col1) Col1
, MIN(tbl.Col2) Col2 
, MIN(tbl.Col3) Col3 
FROM @table tbl
GROUP BY tbl.Col
```

**However, if you have empty rows, then use `MAX()`. Otherwise `MIN()` returns empty rows:**

```
SELECT 
tbl.Col
, MAX(tbl.Col1) Col1
, MAX(tbl.Col2) Col2 
, MAX(tbl.Col3) Col3 
FROM @table tbl
GROUP BY tbl.Col
```

For example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Col  VARCHAR(50),
    Col1 VARCHAR(50), 
    Col2 VARCHAR(50), 
    Col3 VARCHAR(50) 
)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    Col,
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3
)
VALUES
(   'a1', -- Col - varchar(50)
    'x', -- Col1 - varchar(50)
    Null, -- Col2 - varchar(50)
    'x'  -- Col3 - varchar(50)
    )
, ('a1', NULL, 'x', null)
, ('a1', NULL, 'x', null)
, ('b2', 'x', null, null)
, ('b2', null, null, null)
, ('c3', 'x', 'x', 'x')

SELECT 
tbl.Col
, MIN(tbl.Col1) Col1
, MIN(tbl.Col2) Col2 
, MIN(tbl.Col3) Col3 
FROM @table tbl
GROUP BY tbl.Col
```

OUTPUT:

```
Col Col1    Col2    Col3
a1   x        x       x
b2   x       NULL   NULL
c3   x        x       x
```

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, for this result set it works correctly.

Comment: I don't understand. `MIN` skips nulls and `MAX` doesn't? That's new to me.

Comment: `MIN` and `MAX` both ignore nulls So both return the non-null value. Only if two or more non-null values per ID exist, would `MIN` return the lesser value and `MAX` the greater one. This has nothing to do with "empty rows".

Answer (score 3):

use aggregation

```
select col1 ,max(col2),max(col3),max(col4)
form table_name group by col1
```

Answer (score 1):

You want aggregation :

```
select col1, max(col2), max(col2), max(col3)
from table t
group by col1;
```

This assuming blank value as  `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution for such a situation is to simply aggregate and either use `MIN` or `MAX` on the columns.

SQL Server's data type `BIT`, however, is quirky. It's a little like a `BOOLEAN`, but not a real boolean. It is a little like a very limited numeric data type, but it isn't really a numeric type either. And there simply exist no aggregation functions for this data type. In standard SQL you'd have `ANY` and `EVERY` for the `BOOLEAN` type. In PostgreSQL you have `BIT_OR` and `BIT_AND` for `BIT` and `BOOL_OR` and `BOOL_AND` for `BOOLEAN`. SQL Server has nothing.

So convert your columns to a numeric type before using `MIN` (which would be a bitwise AND) or `MAX` (which would be a bitwise OR) on it. E.g.

```
select
  id,
  max(bit1 + 0) as bit1agg,
  max(bit2 + 0) as bit2agg,
  max(bit3 + 0) as bit3agg
from mytable
group by id
order by id;
```

You can also use `CAST` or `CONVERT` instead of course.

Comment: Yep I casted Bit as integer and it works fine :) Thank you for reply